# how to copy and write in specific line

Tags: unix

I want to send a file to a remote server and then copy the only line that exists in it , and then search in another file placed in a remote server for a specific line (standard word in it)
and then replace it without deleting or modifying any thing else in this file

I tried

```
df -h | grep '/dev/md/dsk/d0' | awk '{ print $5 }' |tee ~/test1
scp ~/test1 username@hostname~/holder.txt

ssh username@hostname sed s/"text_to_replace"/text_to_replace_it/g ~/target.txt
```

I was successful in sending the file but nothing changed in the target file ( I tried any text manually within "sed" but nothing happene ?

Thanks & regards

Comment: Does the command work when typed into an interactive ssh shell on the same host?  One possibility: `~/target.txt` will expand to a full filename on the local side.  If your home directory is named differently on the remote side, the file won't exist

Answer (score 0):

```
remove the slash by the way :

sed "/$a/,/$b/!d" input_file > new_file
```

Comment: thank you for replay 
but sorry i don't understand ,, i'm new in unix ^_^

Comment: This should be a comment.